# Why my custom mail changes doesn't appears?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I found the mail template that i want to customize but the changes in the body don't works, there's no apparent change
my xml file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">

        <record id="sale.email_template_edi_sale" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Sales Order: Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order" />
            <field name="email_from">${object.user_id.email_formatted |safe}</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.as_comercial} ${object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'Quotation' or
                'Order'} (Ref ${object.name or 'n/a' })</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
                <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">

                        Hello ${object.partner_id.name} this is a message from ODOO
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
            </field>
            <field name="report_template" ref="action_report_saleorder" />
            <field name="report_name">${(object.name or '').replace('/','_')}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="user_signature" eval="False" />
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize noupdate template like that.Try this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data>
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">

        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">

            <value eval="[('module', '=', 'sale'), ('name', '=', 'email_template_edi_sale')]" />

            </function>

            <value eval ="{'noupdate': False}" />

    </function>
        <record id="sale.email_template_edi_sale" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Sales Order: Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order" />
            <field name="email_from">${object.user_id.email_formatted |safe}</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.as_comercial} ${object.state in ('draft',     'sent') and 'Quotation' or
                'Order'} (Ref ${object.name or 'n/a' })</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
                <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">

                        Hello ${object.partner_id.name} this is a message from ODOO
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
            </field>
            <field name="report_template" ref="action_report_saleorder" />
            <field name="report_name">${(object.name or '').replace('/','_')}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="user_signature" eval="False" />
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
        </record>
        <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">

        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">

            <value eval="[('module', '=', 'sale'), ('name', '=', 'email_template_edi_sale')]" />

            </function>

            <value eval ="{'noupdate': True}" />

    </function>
    </data>
</odoo>
```